# JavaScript / PHP: Get a Client's Month and Day with JS, Pass the Values to PHP Variable

Tags: php, javascript

I want to get day and month from a client's computer, and then pass it to PHP in two separate variables, which would result in something like this:

```
$day_num = 11;
$month_num = 12;
```

I need JavaScript function and PHP function to be separate files, and I need to pass the value 
not in the URL.

I would be grateful for a bit of help from an expert!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Javascript:

If you are using jQuery gettting it back to the server is  *super* easy (if you do it without, see: [How to make an AJAX call without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)):

```
<script language="javascript">
var date = new Date(),
    month = date.getMonth(),
    day = date.getDate();

    $.post('path-to-php.php', { day: day, month: month});  
</script>
```

### PHP:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST['day']);
    var_dump($_POST['month']);
?>
```

### Edit:

`path-to-php.php` is the filename of your php file. It can be absolute or relative, depending on your application. If you wanted to post it to the same file, you could use this instead of `path-to-php.php`: `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>`

Comment: What would be the way to do it without relying on jQuery?

Comment: Looks like jQuery is a better option. Forgive me a novice question: should I include jQuery IN the JS file - or somewhere else?

Comment: There really isn't a clean or easy way to include jQuery in a javascript file. It is doable, though. You include jQuery in the `<head></head>` tag of the page, like this: <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> - this example is using Google's CDN version, so you wouldn't have to host it yourself.

Comment: Happy to help!! Please remember to mark as an answer if this answered your question.

Comment: A couple of quick questions: how do I determine the path-to-php? And what if I needed to pass it within the same page, not between two separate ones?

Answer (score 1):

With javascript:

```
function executeAjax()  { 
var date = new Date(),
var month = date.getMonth(),
var day = date.getDate();

var url="daymonth.php?month="+month+"&day="+day;
var objX=new XMLHttpRequest();
objX.open("GET",url,false);
objX.send(null);
var response=objX.responseText;

}
```

**daymonth.php**

```
<?php
    $day=$_GET['day'];
    $month=$_GET['month'];
?>
```